# C# Windows -Get rid of strange symbols

Tags: c#

Using Xml Deserilization I am  getting value back from xml file and store the values to appropriate controls.

I have an array of email addresses.I am assigning it to textbox as follows.

```
textEmailAddress=string.Join("\n", emp.Emails);
```

( During serilization i split those addresses using : `textEmailAddress.Text.Split(new[] { '\n', ',' });` )

The textBox "textEmailAddress" is getting filled up with email addresses with 'new line' symbols.

I applied

```
textEmailAddress.Text
  = textEmailAddress.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
```

but i am unable to remove the entire newline characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Environment.NewLine` depends on the environment. On Windows it is the string `"\r\n"` (carriage return, line feed). To match

```
textEmailAddress=string.Join("\n", emp.Emails);
```

you will have to do

```
textEmailAddress.Replace("\n", " ");
```

instead of using `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: Please note the Environment.NewLine is not available on the compact framework ... sometimes they have really bright ideas @ MS

Answer (score 0):

In windows, a new line is specified by \r\n, not just \n, so when you join it and split it, you should use \r\n for the Environment.NewLine to properly match it.

Comment: Incorrect. \n works fine for me. Even says so in the documentation I have.